# mousePressed() applied when hovering instead of clicking

Tags: java, processing, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a song player with three buttons (go to prev song, stop song, go to next song). I want to stop the audio playing when the stop button button is clicked using `mousePressed()`.

The problem is, it is applied whenever my mouse is hovering on the area of the button I defined in the `mousePressed()` function. Why is that so? I tried to use other area as well inside the `mousePressed()` and still facing the same problem.

Here is my code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
import processing.sound.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import cc.arduino.*;

Arduino arduino;
Serial myPort;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;
AudioMetaData meta;

Amplitude amp;
AudioIn in;

BeatDetect beat;
BeatListener bl;

SoundFile now_playing;
Waveform waveform;

float DEFAULT_VOL_AMP = 1;


PFont poppins;
PImage prevIcon, playIcon, nextIcon;
boolean prevPressed, playPressed, nextPressed = false;

// ----- songs & waveform -----
String songs[] = {"song1.mp3",
                  "song2.mp3", 
                  "song3.mp3", 
                  "song4.mp3", 
                  "song5.mp3", 
                  "song6.mp3"};
int songsLength = songs.length;
int pointer = 2;

String decibelsLevel = "";
int samples = 60000; // detail waveform
boolean displayWarning = false;
String warning = "WARNING! \n Your song is too loud, it can damage your hearing.";

int prevX, prevY, playX, playY, nextX, nextY, iPrevX, iPrevY, iPlayX, iPlayY, iNextX, iNextY; // posisi x & y dari masing-masing button
int btnSize = 72;
color btnColor, prevBtnColor, playBtnColor, nextBtnColor;


public void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
  poppins = createFont("poppins-regular.ttf", 22);
  textFont(poppins);

  // waveform
  now_playing = new SoundFile(this, songs[pointer]);
  now_playing.loop();
  waveform = new Waveform(this, samples);
  waveform.input(now_playing);
  now_playing.amp(DEFAULT_VOL_AMP);
  
  // scans amplitude level
  amp = new Amplitude(this); in = new AudioIn(this, 0);
  in.start();
  amp.input(now_playing);
  
  // getting song's metadata
  minim = new Minim(this);
  song = minim.loadFile(songs[pointer]);
  meta = song.getMetaData();
  
  // buttons & icons
  btnColor = color(85,103,186);
  prevBtnColor = color(85,103,186);
  prevX = 300; iPrevX = prevX - 25;
  prevY = 400; iPrevY = prevY - 25;
  prevIcon = loadImage("icon_previous.png");
  
  playBtnColor = color(85,103,186); 
  playX = 400; iPlayX = playX - 15;
  playY = 400; iPlayY = playY - 18;
  playIcon = loadImage("icon_play.png");

  
  nextBtnColor = color(85,103,186);
  nextX = 500; iNextX = nextX - 25;
  nextY = 400; iNextY = nextY - 25;
  nextIcon = loadImage("icon_next.png");

}

public void draw() {

  background(49, 65, 161); // blue 
  AmplitudeLevel();
  Waveform();
  
  if (amp.analyze() > 2){
    DisplayWarning();
  }
  else {
    SongDesc();
  }
  
  Buttons();
 mousePressed();
}

public void mousePressed(){
  // prevBtn position
  if (mouseX > prevX-btnSize && mouseX < prevX+btnSize && mouseY > prevY-btnSize && mouseY < prevY+btnSize){
    if (songs[pointer-1] != null) {
      pointer--;
    }
    else {
      pointer = songsLength - 1;
    }
      
  }
  // stopBtn position
  else if (mouseX > playX-btnSize && mouseX < playX+btnSize && mouseY > playY-btnSize && mouseY < playY+btnSize){
    now_playing.stop();
  }
  // nextBtn position
  else if (mouseX > nextX-btnSize && mouseX < nextX+btnSize && mouseY > nextY-btnSize && mouseY < nextY+btnSize){
    if (songs[pointer + 1] != null) {
      pointer++;
    }
    else {
      pointer = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried to debug with the code below. However, the "pressed" printed even though I didn't create any mouse event.

```
boolean alreadyPressed = false
public void mousePressed(){
  if (!alreadyPressed) {
    println("pressed");
    alreadyPressed = true;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance & I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are calling `mousePressed` inside `draw`. The function `mousePressed` itself doesn't check if the mouse is actually pressed. It is just a function that is called every time the mouse is pressed. The checking part is done elsewhere in Processing.

Now that you are calling it in `draw`, every time you `draw`, it executes `mousePressed` function and makes everything that is supposed to be executed on press execute on hover.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you so much! I managed to fix it by adding `&& mousePressed == true` in my if statement for the button position. :)

Comment: That's one way to solve it. Try removing the `mousePressed()` call in `draw`. `mousePressed` should still be called whenever you press the mouse. That would be the more "official" way of solving your problem.